# Branch Points of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm just wondering if someone could help me understand where the other two branch points would be for a function $f(z) = ((za)^3-1)^{-1/3}$ . I can figure out that the first point is at $1/a$ and I have an idea that the 3 points will be joined together by a unit circle however I'm unsure where to go from here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\exp(2\pi i/3)\frac{1}{a}$ and $\exp(4\pi i/3)\frac{1}{a}$ also make the base zero.

Comment: Thank you again Boxwood!